# Can someone help me create this system?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I do yet not know everything about coding with tikz but I am learning. I need to draw this system and I would really appreciate it if someone helped me make this.
[image]

I want it to have the same kind of structure as this system, not too bold just simple and thin.
[image]

Comment: The answer at the duplicated question is much more simple and easy to understand and edit.
[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565712/how-can-i-draw-this-semicircle-with-tikz).
I flagged this question as a duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

Created by Mathcha tool just for fun.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document} 
\tikzset{
pattern size/.store in=\mcSize, 
pattern size = 5pt,
pattern thickness/.store in=\mcThickness, 
pattern thickness = 0.3pt,
pattern radius/.store in=\mcRadius, 
pattern radius = 1pt}
\makeatletter
\pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@pattern@name@_hir4e2rgc}{
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\mcThickness,\mcSize]{_hir4e2rgc}
{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
{\pgfpoint{\mcSize+\mcThickness}{\mcSize+\mcThickness}}
{\pgfpoint{\mcSize}{\mcSize}}
{
\pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
\pgfsetlinewidth{\mcThickness}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\mcSize+\mcThickness}{\mcSize+\mcThickness}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,426); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 426

%Straight Lines [id:da7301701841685078] 
\draw    (161.9,211) -- (430.9,211) ;
\draw [shift={(433.9,211)}, rotate = 180] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da40728898709106365] 
\draw    (285.25,211) -- (285.25,50) ;
\draw [shift={(285.25,47)}, rotate = 450] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
%Shape: Arc [id:dp18126790263663173] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0] (188.52,211.8) .. controls (188.52,211.38) and (188.51,210.95) .. (188.5,210.52) .. controls (188.02,156.61) and (231.99,112.49) .. (286.73,112) .. controls (341.46,111.5) and (386.23,154.81) .. (386.72,208.73) .. controls (386.73,209.65) and (386.72,210.57) .. (386.71,211.49) -- (287.61,209.62) -- cycle ; \draw   (188.52,211.8) .. controls (188.52,211.38) and (188.51,210.95) .. (188.5,210.52) .. controls (188.02,156.61) and (231.99,112.49) .. (286.73,112) .. controls (341.46,111.5) and (386.23,154.81) .. (386.72,208.73) .. controls (386.73,209.65) and (386.72,210.57) .. (386.71,211.49) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da580752990957069] 
\draw    (285.25,211) -- (223.49,141.25) ;
\draw [shift={(221.5,139)}, rotate = 408.48] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da7353205647598391] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (222,140.2) -- (222,210.2) ;
%Rounded Single Corner Rect [id:dp4448054083057227] 
\draw  [pattern=_hir4e2rgc,pattern size=6pt,pattern thickness=0.75pt,pattern radius=0pt, pattern color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0}] (345.9,132.8) .. controls (345.9,130.59) and (344.11,128.8) .. (341.9,128.8) -- (337.9,128.8) -- (337.9,211.2) -- (345.9,211.2) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da7171404110457682] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (188.52,201.8) -- (188.52,221.81) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da728474794651282] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (386.71,201.49) -- (386.71,221.49) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da08529914379962378] 
\draw    (335,219.8) -- (351.9,219.8) ;
\draw [shift={(354.9,219.8)}, rotate = 180] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;
\draw [shift={(332,219.8)}, rotate = 0] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (10.72,-5.15) -- (0,0) -- (10.72,5.15) -- (7.12,0) -- cycle    ;

% Text Node
\draw (250,152.2) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\mathbf{R}$};
% Text Node
\draw (174,221.2) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$-R$};
% Text Node
\draw (381,222.2) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$R$};
% Text Node
\draw (334,225) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$dx$};
% Text Node
\draw (267,46.2) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$y$};
% Text Node
\draw (419,220) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$x$};
% Text Node
\draw (320,160.2) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\hat\mathbf{y}$};
% Text Node
\draw (354,175.2) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$dA$};
% Text Node
\draw (287.25,214.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$O$};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks great but I wanted a more specific system, I updated the post with a picture of the structure. I want it to have the same kind of structure as this system, not too bold just simple and thin. If you really do that it would make my day. I should've written how I wanted the structure to look like, my fault.

Comment: @Muhashka For my humble opinion it is nice and it has the similar structure of the 2nd image: looking the code you can change from bold to normal font to have them thick.